# Compressible gas dynamics in the context of astrophysics

Tags: fluid-dynamics, astrophysics, resource-recommendations, gas

I am looking for a resource that specializes and gives an emphasis on the dynamics of compressible fluids (gas dynamics) preferably in more than one dimensions, but one dimensional is also good, and also preferably in the context of astrophysics.

Answer (score 3):

At the introductory level, [Cathie Clarke's *Principles of Astrophysical Fluid Dynamics*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1107666910) is a good book. It covers pretty much every aspect of fluid dynamics one needs for astrophysics: gravitation, shock waves, magnetic fields, etc. It's been a while since I looked at it, but it surely requires knowledge of vector calculus (I believe she uses vector notation throughout, but it never hurts to know [index notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation) as well).

Another similar book, aimed more for upper-level seniors and graduate students, is [Frank Shu's *The Physics of Astrophysics Volume II: Gas Dynamics*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/189138967X). It covers much of the same topics Clarke's book covers, but with some more details. I don't believe [Vol I: Radiation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1891389769) is needed to understand Vol II, but as the pair is a very good resource it probably won't hurt to pick it up.

On a more programmatical aspect, [Toro's *Riemann Solvers and Numerical Methods*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540252029) and [LeVeque's *Finite Volume Methods for Hyperbolic Problems*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521009243) are pretty much the bible for how to write code that will accurately model fluid flows. In both books, vector calculus and linear algebra are needed. LeVeque's book is written more towards undergraduates, but is good for anyone interested in numerical methods; it also includes references an older version of his Fortran code [*Clawpack*](http://www.clawpack.org/) (an open-source library).