# Book recommendation: Introduction to astrophysical hydrodynamics

Tags: fluid-dynamics, astrophysics, resource-recommendations

I have a PhD in Fluid Dynamics and I would like to have a taste of how the concepts and methods of this field are currently used in Astrophysics research.

Would you have a book recommendation for me? Note that I don't have a solid background in Astrophysics; hence, it would be great that the book contains a comprehensive introduction to this field as well (if such a book does exist).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compressible gas dynamics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/379716/)

Comment: relativistic hydrodynamics?

Comment: @KyleKanos To me, it seems slightly different.

Comment: @Shing Actually I don't know : do you think this matter should be addressed in an introduction?

Comment: @BebiouYaz0 what's different about it? Both questions are asking for fluid dynamics texts from an astrophysics perspective. If I write an answer here, it would be identical to the one I posted there.

Comment: @KyleKanos My question is from the point of view of a fluid dynamicist : I'm not asking about compressible gas dynamics but how/where it pops up in the Astrophysics field. Also I wished the book recommendation was also an introduction to Astrophysics.
But it is indeed possible that my question and the one your refer to have the same answer.

Comment: I have been able to download an university astrophysics book. It deals (at least for the part I went through) with stellar equilibrium at stellar scale with little motion . To resume in a line onion like structure with shells in equilibrium. I would at least recommend it as a donwladable introduction to stellar physics. Shall I look in my pc later?