# Book on numerical solution of PDEs

Tags: fluid-dynamics, resource-recommendations, computational-physics, differential-equations

I would like to learn how to solve partial differential equations (first and second order, e.g. Poisson, etc...) numerically with finite differences. Which book can be recommended if one want it to learn at the level of a physicist and not a mathematician? Of course I know that the topic is not trivial, but I would like to learn how to solve concrete problems in fluid dynamics without studying mathematics for three years first. In other words: it shouldn't be too trivial, but not too demanding either.

To put an example: Given an initial 2D velocity stream field $u(x,y,t=0), v(x,y, t=0)$ I would like to solve numerically for $u(x,y,t)$, $v(x,y,t)$ by empoing the vorticity equation for an incompressible fluid:

$$\zeta(x, y, t) = \vec \nabla \times \vec v(x, y, t)$$

$$\frac{\partial \zeta}{\partial t} + u(x,y) \cdot \frac{\partial \zeta}{\partial x} + v(x,y) \cdot \frac{\partial \zeta}{\partial y} = 0$$

This is the simplest equation in fluid dynamics. Regardless of whether it is realistic in nature or not, I would like to be able to solve such a model problem.

EDIT:

Originally I didn't want to put the original problem here, but here it is:

The problem in particular was:

As an exercise there were given four Rankine vortices of radius R=1 (1...4) at positions (0, 0), (-2,0), (2,0), (0,1). Vorticities for 2, 3, 4 are given as 1, 1, -3. The question was how to choose vorticity of a fifth vortex at (0, -4) so that vortex 1 is not moving. Considering all vortices as rather solid objects and by focusing on their centers the simple answer is of course -12 due to 1/r behavior outside R.

[image]

But then we had some discussion about how to interpret the exercise and came to the conclusion, that it is more complex: by viewing the velocity field all vortices (including 1) are not only moving around but also become severely distorted as time passes. The big question then was not how to draw the initial field (see image) but how this initial field develops with time.

Assuming conservation of vorticity the equation above must be fulfilled together with the condition, that the velocity field is free of divergence. I was wondering, how such problem can be formulated in terms of finite differences and finally is solved.

Comment: What is your background? Which applications you're most interested in? Anyway, your question sounds a lot like that question I'd never want to listen to

Comment: My background is a degree in physics, but no experience in the area of ​​finite difference methods. I added my question above to show what I want to do. What do you mean with your last comment?

Comment: Those equations are not the simplest equations in fluid dynamics, and that one is not even a well-defined problem: time-dependent PDEs need for initial conditions and boundary conditions, and you should be able to write them using the functions of your problem: can you?. Moreover, the shape of the domain usually may have some influence on the trade off simplicity-generality of the solver. Do you need to solve it on your own? Please, some more details

Comment: Want to do it in C? Numerical Recipes in C: https://www.amazon.com/Numerical-Recipes-Scientific-Computing-Second/dp/0521431085

Comment: Looks like there is a newer edition for C++: https://www.amazon.com/Numerical-Recipes-3rd-Scientific-Computing-dp-0521880688/dp/0521880688/

Comment: Apparently it is available online for free: https://numerical.recipes/

Comment: I own Numerical Recipes already for quite a long time. It is a good book but it is for my taste to "shallow" in terms of underlaying theory.

Comment: @basics: My stated problem has at least one initial condition at t=0. There are no boundary conditions because the 2D space is assumed to be infinitely extended. The question stems from a recent exercise in atmospheric dynamics, but goes definitely beyond that. I can describe these in my original question above, but point out that I want to learn the method and that I'm not concerned with this one problem in particular. I just want to be able to solve similar problems myself AND (!) also understand what I'm doing.

Comment: @basics: now I understand why boundary conditions are required...

Comment: with infinite domain, it's not that easy to use finite difference methods, or grid-based methods

Comment: @hft NR is copyrighted materials, usage of their code in yours means you have to obey their copyright laws which are [*extremely restrictive*](http://mingus.as.arizona.edu/~bjw/software/boycottnr.html) (like you literally cannot share it with anyone, including yourself on a separate computer!). I would strongly advise against recommending that useless trash.

Comment: @MichaelW : I answered a [related question just the other day](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/790387/25301) which probably would suffice as an answer here.

Comment: @KyleKanos It's a book for learning, like it says: "[T]his book is intended as a text and reference book, for reading and study purposes only." Anyways, they can't copyright the algorithms, which are intangible, and I doubt they have the money to litigate about anything other than literal copying (if that). People can choose to license their material however they want, just because they aren't giving everything away for free does not make it a bad book.

Comment: @KyleKanos (And, apparently, that book is "to [sic] shallow" for OP, so I guess it's a moot point.)

Comment: Sorry for the typo... Anyway, I already own this book and while it has done good work in the past, it's not what I'm looking for when it comes to what I want to learn. The book recommended by HiddenBabel (see answer) might be my choice at the moment.

Comment: @hft *Anyways, they can't copyright the algorithms, which are intangible,* once you put the algo into source code (literally the intent of NR), it's 100% copyrightable. Whether they fight it or not, you are bound to the copyright. I'd also argue it's a bad book because it's severely dated, most algos have been improved since the 1980's when it was first written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to get hands-on and actually solve problems, then try [this book](https://hplgit.github.io/fdm-book/doc/pub/book/html/decay-book.html) freely available online.

> **Finite Difference Computing with Partial Differential Equations**
> Hans Petter Langtangen
>
> There are so many excellent books on finite difference methods for ordinary and partial differential equations that writing yet another one requires a different view on the topic. The present book is not so concerned with the traditional academic presentation of the topic, but is focused at teaching the practitioner how to obtain reliable computations involving finite difference methods.

It covers some common schemes for implementing finite differences, boundary conditions, error analysis, and some pitfalls you can encounter. There are several example problems. The code is in Python, and some of the text is dedicated to implementing Python, but the lessons on finite differences can of course easily be applied elsewhere.

However, to touch on your subject matter, I don't believe it is common to handle many fluid dynamics problems with finite differences. One reason is that conservation laws can be very difficult to implement with high precision, so you have to devise increasingly complicated methods to enforce that conservation. But things like the convection-diffusion equation can be solved with finite differences just fine.

Comment: Just to ask: "I don't believe it is common to handle many fluid dynamics problems with finite differences." What approaches are used instead?

Comment: @MichaelW [Finite Volume](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_volume_method) and [Finite Element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_element_method) are the two more common approaches. Each has their advantages/disadvantages, so it usually depends on scenario design and/or your advisor's experience.

Comment: You could look at vortex methods, if you're mainly interested in this kind of problem

Answer (score 2):

Michael Zingale has written a rather extensive open-source textbook on numerically solving PDEs, albeit with an astrophysical context (which shouldn't really matter, the methods are largely the same), which is available on [his github page](https://open-astrophysics-bookshelf.github.io/numerical_exercises/).

The first few chapters are relatively light on maths (mostly PDE classification, finite difference background, numerical errors), but the text as a whole largely requires familiarity with Linear Algebra and PDEs.

Chapter 3 is where Finite Volume Methods (FVM) are introduced to distinguish it from Finite Difference (FDM). It is in Chapter 5 that really begins the mathy-programming of improvements of FVM over FDM and how to convert PDEs into FVM algorithms. [Euler's equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_equations_(fluid_dynamics)), which are a 0-viscosity limit of Navier-Stokes equation) are covered in Chapter 7 while their numeric implementation are in Chapter 8.

It makes frequent reference to his Python implementation of hydrodynamics code, called [*pyro2*](https://github.com/python-hydro/pyro2/), though it's not really a tutorial on using it (which exists in github repo for pyro2).